# How does one get RESTful data via google http client

Tags: rest

I am trying to use the google http client library to access a server that adheres to the REST principles, but I cannot figure out how to use the Google http library to get that data. Here is the information I am trying to access.

```
GET /appdata/:appKey
Host: baas.kinvey.com
Authorization: [Basic Auth with app credentials]
```

I have searched online and read several [tutorials](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-beginners-introduction-to-http-and-rest/) and even tried to follow the [google http example](https://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/source/browse/googleplus-simple-cmdline-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/googleplus/cmdline/simple/GooglePlusSample.java?repo=samples) but I still can't figure out what I am supposed to do to get that data. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: what code have you tried?  what errors are you getting?  Do you have an app key?

Comment: Ok, what I am saying is I don't know where to start. I have tried googling some sources but they haven't been helpful. @Lordkain Which book should I read? Guns,Germs and Steel? Or maybe One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest?